# Copy specific data using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy and paste my certain values if the Col and row parameters are met

but it seems the code is running but there is no data showing up on the output

I have tried different methods but none of have been successful

```
Sub SalesDownload()

Dim wbCopyTo As Workbook
Dim wsCopyTo As Worksheet
Dim wbCopyFrom As Workbook
Dim wsCopyFrom As Worksheet
Dim vFile As Variant
Dim Channel As String
Dim Month As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim k As Integer, l As Integer



Set wbCopyTo = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsCopyTo = Worksheets("Sales")
'-------------------------------------------------------------
'Open file with data to be copied

vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xl*)," & _
"*.xl*", 1, "Select Excel File", "Open", False)

'If Cancel then Exit
If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then
Exit Sub
Else
Set wbCopyFrom = Workbooks.Open(vFile, ReadOnly:=True)
Set wsCopyFrom = wbCopyFrom.Worksheets("FMS1")
End If

'--------------------------------------------------------------
'Copy Range
'wsCopyFrom.Range("C5:O16").Copy
'wsCopyTo.Range("a1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
'Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False



For i = 6 To 18



Channel = wsCopyFrom.Cells(i, 3).Value
For j = 4 To 39
Month = wsCopyFrom.Cells(5, j).Value

For k = 2 To 14
For l = 2 To 18
If wsCopyTo.Cells(k, 1).Value = Channel Then
If wsCopyTo.Cells(2, l).Value = Month Then
wsCopyFrom.Activate
wsCopyFrom.Cells(i, j).Value.Copy
wsCopyTo.Activate
wsCopyTo.Cells(k, l).Select.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End If
End If

Next l
Next k
Next j
Next i

'Close file that was opened
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wbCopyFrom.Close

MsgBox "Done!!!"


'SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: It would help if you explained what your code should be doing. Even better, show some sample data and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Should you consider copying data without using excel api?
Instead of

```
wsCopyFrom.Activate
wsCopyFrom.Cells(i, j).Value.Copy
wsCopyTo.Activate
wsCopyTo.Cells(k, l).Select.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Use variables, for example:

```
set value = wsCopyFrom.Cells(i, j).Value
wsCopyTo.Cells(k, l).Value = value;
```

It'll be faster and won't depend on excel UI.